# How do electrical permits work in New Jersey?

Tags: electrical, permitting

I recently installed recessed lights in my 2nd floor condominium. Later, I was told by friend that I need permit to do that.

My questions are:

- Can I take permit now and have inspector inspect my work or it is too late?
- What should I do?

Comment: I removed the cost question as that's subject to the whims of the NJ state legislature and (since it's Dec 15th) may change in 17 days... I also did a bit of formatting.

Comment: "*How do electrical permits work in New Jersey?*" You talk to a guy who knows a guy to arrange a meeting.  Meet  in the back room of a little restaurant and make "arrangements"

Comment: Just a question , was there a new circuit installed or was this added to an existing circuit? This may sound funny but how many floors? 
What wiring method did you use (nmb or Romex, metal clad or armor clad sometimes called BX , or conduit of some type).  
The above questions make a big deal of who can do what. 
NJ on 2017 code. No update on when going to the 2020 code.

Comment: I did not install new circuit from panel. I used existing circuit to supply power to newly installed recessed light wiring. Just ran new cables for recessed lights in ceiling. I used 14/2 (and 14/3 for 3 way switch) romex cable.

Comment: Why not have it inspected? At best you'll pass if not you'll fix unsafe problems.

Comment: I don't think you'll incur the wrath of the building inspector nor should you be fined. did the install follow Code?

Comment: @AlaskaMan  This isn't a useful comment, but I was literally laughing out loud at your comment. I was thinking the same thing!   Like you said:  "I know a guy who knows a guy that can take care of that thing for you.  Yeah, that thing.  No the second thing, What up with the first thing? fugedaboutit, it's taken care of"   .,...sorry, not a useful comment, but in these trying times, we need to take a moment to share humor.   Again, great comment, alaska man.

Comment: I would verify with your jurisdiction. Some allow minor extensions without a permit and in the example of a receptacle no requirement to update to arc fault in a bedroom for extensions under 5’ this is legal in my state. The data I found said any new work and some replacements like water heaters and AC units do require permits. A homeowner can do there electrical in NJ. If you did not over fill a junction box to run the new lights (and boxes were used) you should be able to get it approved. If the building itself is 3 or less floors above grade, above that different wire methods are required.